# Decreasing margins

Tags: margins

How to decrease the the gap between the number of the page and the last line in the page to be as in the screenshot blew ?! noting that I’m using `\documentclass{article}` .

[image]

Comment: And how you define page layout? Do you use `geometry` packages? By it this easy to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Just telling us your class tells us something, but not a whole lot.

Comment: That page number looks far too close to the text to my eye .... (It is easy to do it, but it doesn't mean it should be done, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a page-by-page basis, insert

```
\enlargethispage{<len>}
```

on the page you want to have content closer to the footer. Here `<len>` should be a multiple of `\baselineskip`.

For adjusting the distance globally, you could use [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), setting the `skip` to the `foot`er to `0pt`:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=0pt}
```

Comment: Can I ask another question here regarding the same subject ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `article` class without other page layout modifications, it should suffice to redefine `\footskip`:

```
\setlength\footskip{1em}
```

Note that the length is the distance between the bottom of the main text and the *bottom* of the footer.

Or, to adjust relative to the default you could do (e.g.)

```
\addtolength\footskip{-20pt}
```

Either of these will result in moving the page number closer to the main text (without moving the text margin).

Comment: Your answer is greatly appreciated Ms. Emma :)